# Howto exclude a source folder when using GWT Compile in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwt-compiler

I have a GWT Project in Eclipse with 2 source folders.

/java this folder contains the application code, that should be GWT compiled
/test this folder contains unit test code that should not be GWT compiled (is not possible.

The packages inside these folders are the same so that I can unit test package private classes and methods as well.

When I use the GWT Compile button in Eclipse I can not configure somehow that I only want to compile what is in the /java folder. Am I overlooking something ? It makes it impossible to use -strict compilation in Eclipse.

Comment: I'd say that if Eclipse is your "build tool", you should follow Eclipse's rules, and create a distinct project for your tests.

Comment: well, its not the only build tool, the end product is build with ant, but the eclipse plugin makes GWT compile convenient. But indeed, I could split up the unittest in separate projects.

Comment: In your case, I think I'd either use Ant, or create a launch configuration for the GWT Compiler that doesn't include `test/`; or don't use `-strict` from Eclipse…